# An infinite sequence a for which prime divisors of $a_i^2+1$ are in the set $S$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

For polynomial $p(x)=x^2+1$ is there an infinite sequence $A$ for which all prime divisors of each $a_i^2+1$ are in the finite set $S$?

I tried to show that the answer is positive: let $b$ be an element of this sequence and let $d$ be a number whose all prime divisors are in $s$ if we prove that there is such a $d$ for which $d(b^2+1)$ is in the form $x^2+1$ we are done!
Which is to evaluate $x^2-db^2=d-1$. It's a bit close to Pell's equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a finite set of primes $S$, there are at most finitely many relatively prime $S$-units whose sum is a perfect square (or, more generally, a perfect power). Such a result follows from bounds for linear forms in logarithms (this is certainly in the book of Shorey and Tijdeman). This implies a negative answer to your question.

A straightforward way to see this in your case would be to note that every $S$-unit can be written as $ab^3$ where $a$ is cube-free and there are precisely $3^{\#S}$ choices for $a$. Your problem can thus be reduced to finding the ``integral points'' on the (finite) collection of Mordell curves of the shape
$$
Y^2 = X^3 - a^2.
$$